# How to create http request to get Facebook server response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, request, httpresponse

I need Facebook server response but don't want to redirect. In this code, "ActionResult LoginWithFacebook" is redirecting(i.e sending url) to Facebook server, and then Facebook returns a code in "ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)". My problem is that, i don't want to redirect to Facebook server but want to send url(i.e loginUrl.AbsoluteUri) and to get response(code) in return.. . . . Is there any method to do this? I have heard something like http resquest can send link/url and get response(code) but i don't know how to do that. . . . I need help for this

```
private Uri RedirectUri
        {
            get
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
                uriBuilder.Query = null;
                uriBuilder.Fragment = null;
                uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");
                return uriBuilder.Uri;
            }
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult LoginWithFacebook()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = "my_App_Id",
                client_secret = "my_App_Secret",
                redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
                response_type = "code",
                scope = "email",
            });
            return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);

        }

        public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
        {
            //rest of code
        }
```

Comment: No, that is of course not possible. You can not just request the login dialog URL “in the background” - it is absolutely important that users can verify via the browser address bar that they are indeed entering their login credentials to Facebook, and not some phishing site.

Comment: Ok, i understand,

Comment: Now can we avoid redirection (return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri) ) ? any otherway? my main problem is redirection.

Comment: Then you have to handle login client-side, using the JS SDK. The server-side login does not work without redirect, that is an integral component to the whole process.

Comment: Thanks CBroe sir. . . .